# Update a SQL XML Field node value for a given attribute

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a table with the following format:

```
int IndexField
xml ConfigField
```

A ConfigField field value might look similar to

```
 <Parameters>
      <Parameter Type="Config" Name="Prefix">hd</Parameter>
      <Parameter Type="Config" Name="PgNumber">2</Parameter>
      <Parameter Type="Config" Name="IsValid">False</Parameter>
    </Parameters>
```

I would like to know the SQL Server syntax to modifythe Parameters XML node for the `PgNumber` value from 2 to 3   `where IndexField = 22`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible XQuery expression to be passed to the SQL Server's [`modify()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187093%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) method for updating value of `<Parameter Name='PgNumber'>` element :

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET ConfigField.modify('
        replace value of 
            (/Parameters/Parameter[@Name="PgNumber"]/text())[1] 
        with 3
    ')
WHERE IndexField = 22
```

**<kbd>[`Sqlfiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b5a4/3)</kbd>**

Notice that in XPath/XQuery you need to put `@` at the beginning of attribute name to reference an XML attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You can use function [`modify()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187093(v=sql.110).aspx) and correct XQuery to set the value that you need. The syntax is quite tricky though. In your case you should be able to use such query:

```
UPDATE YourTableName
SET ConfigField.modify('replace value of (/Parameters/Pararameter[@Name="PgNumber"]/text())[1] with "3"')
WHERE IndexField = 22
```

Comment: I ran that and the message said 1 row affected but when i select again it does not look as if the PgNumber was changed

Comment: not sure if this matters but I should add that I am using sql 2012.   thanks so much for any help

Comment: @jvoigt Sorry, it was my typo - I missed `@` symbol, which is required for attribute values. I updated the answer, it should be working now

Comment: Yes that was the issue.  That worked between your answer and har07 reminder of the @